# compare two .csv files column by column

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv

I am trying to write a python script that compares two excel files, column by column.
I have only written a script that compares if the files are identical(i.e same shape, rows, and columns), but I have a column in one of the files that has been added (i.e not present in the other file) and I do not want to compare them. How can I do this?

this is what I have for comparing if two files are exactly the same

```
  
import pandas as pd 
  
#Reading two Excel Sheets 
  
sheet1 = pd.read_csv("crystal.csv") 
sheet2 = pd.read_csv("reformatted_crystal.csv") 
  
# Iterating the Columns Names of both Sheets 
for i,j in zip(sheet1,sheet2): 
     
    # Creating empty lists to append the columns values     
    a,b =[],[] 
  
    # Iterating the columns values 
    for m, n in zip(sheet1[i],sheet2[j]): 
  
        # Appending values in lists 
        a.append(m) 
        b.append(n) 
  
    # Iterating the list's values and comparing them 
    for m, n in zip(range(len(a)), range(len(b))): 
        if a[m] != b[n]: 
            print('Column name : \'{}\' and Row Number : {}'.format(i,m))
```

Comment: [`pd.DataFrame.compare`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.compare.html)

Comment: @ALollz that compares all of the columns

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to drop it permanently, maybe you can use a temp for sheet2 dataframe ?

```
import pandas as pd 
  
#Reading two Excel Sheets 
  
sheet1 = pd.read_csv("crystal.csv") 
sheet2 = pd.read_csv("reformatted_crystal.csv")
sheet2  = sheet2.loc[:,sheet1.columns ] 
  
# Iterating the Columns Names of both Sheets 
for i,j in zip(sheet1,sheet2): 
     
    # Creating empty lists to append the columns values     
    a,b =[],[] 
  
    # Iterating the columns values 
    for m, n in zip(sheet1[i],sheet2[j]): 
  
        # Appending values in lists 
        a.append(m) 
        b.append(n) 
  
    # Iterating the list's values and comparing them 
    for m, n in zip(range(len(a)), range(len(b))): 
        if a[m] != b[n]: 
            print('Column name : \'{}\' and Row Number : {}'.format(i,m))
```

Comment: hmm, is it not possible to compare each column only ? I might have several columns that are in one file and not in the other

Comment: @mei yes possible. you can get the intersection of two by  list(set(sheet1.columns) & set(sheet2.columns)) and then you can use that intersection list in loop.

Comment: sorry, but could you provide the code for that?